# How to Get WP_Customize_Image_Control content?

Tags: theme-customizer, oop

I want to get WP_Customize_Manager controls from my frontend with ajax. This is possible? I looking for a solution on the internet, but I have not found so far any useful documentation about this...

I hope here is a way to get the controls LIKE this (the example not working...):

```
function ajax_control() {
    echo WP_Customize_Manager::get_control( 'blog_header' )->get_content;
}
```

I have experience in PHP OOP (even if this unclear based on my question ...), so if you just can write for me some keywords in this subject (Get Customize Controls outside of wp-admin/customize.php), please help!

Additional:
Based on the above example, I adding the control (blog_header) like this:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'blog_header',
    array(
        'type' => 'theme_mod',
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    )
);
$wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'blog_header' )
);
```

And I can callback the mod with get_theme_mod( 'blog_header'), so I just interested about the CALLBACK OF THE CONTROLS FROM THE FRONTEND.